# How to calculate Paypal payment fee

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I have implemented Paypal express checkout method in my freelancing site. But the problem is that Paypal deducts transfer fee from transferred amount.

For example, Client posts a job for $200, when he pays $200 to site, site receives $190 more or less. How to tackle this problem.

**Code:**

```
<form class="deposit_form" method="post" name="frmPayPal" id="" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">

<input type="hidden" name="business" value="myaccount-facilitator@your-musicians.com">                                 
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo base_url()?>desk">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base_url()?>desk">                                
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo base_url()?>payment/notify">
<input type="hidden" name="succ_url" value="<?php echo base_url()?>payment/notify">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="abc">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="payment_type" value="instant">
<input type="hidden" name="TaxTotal" value="0">                                                              
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="handling" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $key['fee'] ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $key['id'].','.$session['id'];?>">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-credit-card" style="font-size:14px;"></i> Deposit</button>
</form>
```

Does Paypal provide a specific formula to calculate payment fee? so that I can charge more
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Paypal always charges transaction fee on the seller/vendor, nothing is free, you have to factor in those charges in your pricing

Comment: What is your question exactly? Either charge your customer the fee by raising your price or find a new method of collection payment. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: Do they deduct a fixed amount of payment fee so that I can charge that much amount separately?

Comment: @SoftwareCarpenter "Does Paypal provide a specific formula to calculate payment fee"
Question edited

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for PayPal, not StackOverflow.

Comment: @Mr.Llama looks like this question is about an HTML element or anything to configure payment fees. Even if the answer is not programming oriented, this has to do with HTML for using PayPal.

Comment: Well, Paypal developer's support section has a link to stack-overflow to "ask the community" and the community says ask from Paypal.

I posted the question, so if someone who knows can help. I searched a lot and haven't found it. It might be helpful for others too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is UK specific, so may differ if you're not in the UK https://www.paypal.com/uk/merchantrate You can work out the charges based of that.

If you need another currency, just google *"PayPal merchant rates"* and you should get your regions relevant info.

US version: https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/merchant-fees
Not quite as simple, but looks like 2.9% + $0.30 for US fees and 3.9% + fixed fee for international fees

So for US transactions it should be in your case `($200 * 0.029) + $0.3 = $6.10`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It will really help me a lot.